# Can we somehow use array[i] instead of *(array+i)?

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, compilation, stl

In C++, when I have to use an array inside some function, I pass the array  as an argument and get a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. While it is okay to use, and not much of a hassle to use a pointer, I was wondering if there exists some in-built header file, or any other set of instructions, by which when I want to access the `i`-th element of the array I can simply write `array[i]` and it gets read by the compiler as `*(array+i)`?

It would be great if one exists, since it would make it quite uniform and easy to code, since all the times when I use vectors I can access the i-th element just by `vector[i]` while in array I have to use it the other way `*(array+i)`.

Also, is there some reason why the developers of C++ chose to return pointers to an array instead of the object itself?

Comment: Way back in the 1970s when  C was being developed, you couldn't afford to pass arrays by value. You didn't have the spare CPU power to perform the copying and if you did, you probably didn't have the RAM, so always passing and returning by reference was an elegant solution. C++ tried to hew close to C++in the early days and while the two languages have drifted apart significantly, there's a lot of legacy code that would stop working if the array rules changed now. Instead now we recommend using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) when you want value semantics.

Comment: @user4581301 That is not actually true. There is a reason why arrays are decayed in C, but it is not because 'you could not afford to pass it'

Answer (score 12):

If `a` is a pointer and `i` has an integral type, then `a[i]` is always the same as `*(a+i)`. There is no need to include a header or anything to make it work.

Comment: Wow , thanks . Somehow I didn't try a[i] ever and was in the wrong perception all along

Comment: As a funny side note: This is why it is also valid to say `i[a]` or `5[a]`. Not very useful and greatfuly not seen in the wild. :-)

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering if there exists some in-built header file or any other set of instructions by which when I want to access the i-th element of the array I can simply write array[i] and it gets read by the compiler as *(array+i)

No, there is no such header or set of instructions, because it is part of the language.

For a pointer and an integral type, `a[i]` **means** `*(a+i)`.  This is such a strong statement that:

```
int base_array[3]={1,2,3}; // an array of 3 elements
int* ptr_array = base_array; // base_array "decays" to a pointer to the first element
std::cout << 2[ptr_array] << "\n"; // huh?!?!
```

prints 3, because `*(2+ptr_array)` is `3`; ie, *it even works backwards*.

Comment: I was always wondering if this was ever a designed feature, or just a quirk of generally weak type of early C, which later people somehow did feel obliged to preserve in C++ for backward compatibility we could do without?..

Comment: @SergeyA In C, pointer arithmetic comes from assembly/machine code, and arrays "decaying" to pointers is how indexing works (just like machine code).  I suspect the "backwards" bit is an accident more than anything (plus the fact that "well it has no other meaning, what is the harm" bias).  Note that `std::array` has no such similar backwards trick.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of pointer arithmetic and std::array, just curious if it really is designed (even under "why not" theory) or purely random thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we somehow use array[i] instead of *(array+i)?

Yes, we can. Those expressions are practically identical. The subscript operator is much more readable, so I recommend using that.

> I was wondering if there exists some in-built header file

You don't need to include any header.

> while in array i have to use it the other way *(array+i)

Just because you can, doesn't mean that you have to. You don't have to use it the other way.

P.S. Besides arrays and vectors, we can also use the subscript operator with a pointer to element of an array.

---

> Also, is there some reason why the developers of C++ chose to return pointers to an array instead of the object itself?

Because sometimes indirection is necessary or useful.

Comment: Not "practically", but just identical.

Comment: @SergeyA Not identical, because they are different sequences of characters. There is also a subtle difference in operator precedence.

Comment: Fair enough, but that could be misleading depending on how the sentence is read. Can you elaborate on operator precedence diff?

Comment: @SergeyA `Can you elaborate on operator precedence diff?` Subscript operator and unary indirection operator have different precedence "rank". Consider for example `array[i]++` vs `*(array+i)++`. As such, they aren't identical and cannot be substituted with one another in every case without other changes.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, `*(array+i)++` doesn't contain an sub-*expression* `*(array+i)`. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's kind of my entire point :)

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
> a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
> “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped
> enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T”
> shall be a completely-defined object type. The expression E1[E2] is
> identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7
> for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ],
> except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue
> if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

So these expressions `array[i]` and `*( array + i )` are evaluated the same way whether `array` in this expressions is an array designator or a pointer to first element of an array,

Moreover these expressions `array[i]` and `i[array]` are also evaluated the same way.

Arrays are non-modifianle lvalues so you may not return an array from a function.  If to use an array designator in a return statement it will be converted to pointer to its first element. As a result arrays do not have the copy assignment operator.

On the other hand you can return a reference to an array provided that it doesn not have automatic storage duration.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 5;

decltype( auto ) f( int ( &a )[N], int init )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = init++;
    }
    
    return a;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[N];
    
    decltype( auto ) ra = f( a, 0 );
    
    std::cout << sizeof( ra ) << '\n';
    
    for ( const auto &item : ra )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
20
0 1 2 3 4
```